# How to fix SOQL Query Stored XSS

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, stored-xss, reflected-xss

I have given my code for Security code Scanner but it is given the following error due to

```
String attachmentQuery = 'SELECT id,E2CAdv__Attachment__c, E2CAdv__CaseId__c, E2CAdv__Attachment_links__c, E2CAdv__Comment__c FROM E2CAdv__Comment_Attachments__c WHERE E2CAdv__Comment__c =:caseCommentIds';
List<E2CAdv__Comment_Attachments__c> attachmentData = Database.query(attachmentQuery);
               

for(E2CAdv__Comment_Attachments__c att : attachmentData){
    links.add(att.E2CAdv__Attachment_links__c);
 }
```

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/326855/edit) your question to show how you generate the attachmentQuery- there will be some direct concatenation of a value without encoding single quotes or something like that.

Comment: Not as a comment. Edit the question.

Comment: OK, so what is the context of execution for this query and where do the results go?

Comment: I am adding full code with problem screenshot.

Comment: Can you include the full stack trace that Checkmarx generated? There is something about the collected links and how it is used that Checkmarx doesn't like. Have you looked at their [documentation on XSS](https://www.checkmarx.com/knowledge/knowledgebase/XSS)?

Comment: (Please also explain where caseCommentIds binding variable is initialized and from what...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, it looks like most probably is a false positive. If you change your code to be:

```
for(E2CAdv__Comment_Attachments__c att : [SELECT id,E2CAdv__Attachment__c, E2CAdv__CaseId__c, E2CAdv__Attachment_links__c, E2CAdv__Comment__c FROM E2CAdv__Comment_Attachments__c WHERE E2CAdv__Comment__c =:caseCommentIds]) { 
    links.add(att.E2CAdv__Attachment_links__c); 
}
```

The issue will most probably dissapear.

The scanner will usually report every reference to Database.query where the String query passed as an argument is not directly single quotes escaped, but changing string query by the example above should fix your problem.